# Does Islam permit euthanasia?

Tags: suicide, fatwa, medical

> **Definition:** Euthanasia, also known as assisted suicide, physician-assisted suicide (dying) , doctor-assisted dying (suicide) , and more loosely termed mercy killing, basically means to take a deliberate action with the express intention of ending a life to relieve intractable (persistent, unstoppable) suffering. Some interpret euthanasia as the practice of ending a life in a painless manner.

If a patient is suffering great pain from a disease, and there is no hope left for him/her with today's technology, can he/she have euthanasia?

I know that Islam prohibits suicide in general. What about his special kind of suicide? Is it permissible? Is there any example application in Sunnah?

Comment: Related: [Is it haram to stop supporting one who is brain dead?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/is-it-haram-to-stop-supporting-one-who-is-brain-dead)

Answer (score 9):

It is Haram (prohibited) for a patient to hasten their death, whether by committing suicide or by taking medication to kill themselves. It is also Haram for a doctor, a nurse, or any other person to carry out the patient’s request, even if their disease is incurable. Anyone who assists in this shares in the sin, because they intentionally kill a human, whose life is protected by Shari‘ah (Islamic law), without a right. There are clear Nas (Islamic texts from the Qur’an or the Sunnah) prohibiting the killing of a human being without a right. Allah (Exalted be He) says:

> ...and kill not anyone whom Allâh has forbidden, except for a just
>   cause (according to Islâmic law). **[Surah Al-Anam 6:151]**

And:

> And do not kill yourselves (nor kill one another). Surely, Allâh is
>   Most Merciful to you. And whoever commits that through aggression and
>   injustice, We shall cast him into the Fire, and that is easy for
>   Allâh. **[Surah Al-Nisa 4:29]**

Also, it was authentically reported on the authority of Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) said:

> Anyone who kills themselves with a piece of iron (a weapon) will have
>   that piece of iron in their hand and will be stabbing their stomach
>   with it in the Fire of Hell forever, abiding eternally therein. Anyone
>   who drinks poison and kills themselves will be drinking it in the Fire
>   of Hell forever, abiding eternally therein. And anyone who throws
>   themselves from (the top of) a mountain and kills themselves will be
>   throwing themselves down in the Fire of Hell forever, abiding
>   eternally therein. **(Agreed upon by Al-Bukhari and Muslim)**

**For example from Sunnah:**

Jundub ibn ‘Abdullah Al-Bajaly (may Allah be pleased with him) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) said:

> Among the nations before you there was a man who got wounded, and
>   growing impatient (with pain), he took a knife and cut his hand with
>   it. The blood did not stop until he died. Allah (Exalted be He) said,
>   **‘My slave hastened to bring about his demise; I have forbidden
>   Paradise to him.’ (Agreed upon by Al-Bukhari and Muslim; this is the
>   wording of Al-Bukhari)**

Therefore, the Prophet (peace be upon him) forbade people to wish for death to put an end to their suffering. In a Hadith on the authority of Anas ibn Malik (may Allah be pleased with him), he reported that the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) said:

> None of you should wish for death because of a calamity that has
>   befallen them; but if it is unavoidable to do so, let them say, ‘O
>   Allah, make me live as long as life is better for me and make me die
>   if death is better for me.’ **(Related by Al-Bukhari and Muslim; this is
>   the wording of Al-Bukhari)**

Since it is forbidden to merely wish or ask Allah for death, committing suicide or assisting in it is considered a violation of Allah’s Laws and a transgression of the sacred boundaries set by Allah. **Doing this is inconsistent with being patient with what is decreed by Allah.**

It challenges Allah’s Divine Decree and Predestination, and shows dissatisfaction with Allah’s Wisdom of testing His servants with evil and good as trial for them. Allah (Exalted be He) says:

> ...and We shall make a trial of you with evil and with good. **[Surah Al-Anbiya 21:35]**

Allah may try and afflict some of His servants with illness and He is the All-Wise in what He decrees and the All-Knowing of what is best for His servants, as this may bring goodness for the servant, increase their Hasanat (rewardable good deeds), the strength of their faith, and bring them closer to Allah (Glorified be He) through their resignation (to His Will), entreaties, submission, Tawakkul (putting one’s trust in Allah), and supplications to Him. If someone is afflicted with an illness, they should hope for Allah’s Reward and bear with patience their affliction. Showing patience over affliction can gain Allah’s Good Pleasure and increase heavenly reward and elevate the servant to a higher degree in the hereafter.

**Source:** [Using euthanasia to end suffering](http://www.alifta.com/Fatawa/FatawaChapters.aspx?View=Page&PageID=9767&PageNo=1&BookID=7)

Answer (score 0):

Islam doesn't permit euthanasia, as [it is believed] that life is sacred and a gift from God (Allah) and it ultimately belongs to Him. Therefore, when we die and how we die is up to Him [to decide]. And we as humans shouldn't interfere with this. Euthanasia and suicide is Haram, that [means it] is forbidden in Islam.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam Se the Q&A site about Islam. We are not like the typical internet forum so please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model. I also recommend you to read [answer].